# Way to improve "show me this decimal number to M places, don't use scientific notation"?

Tags: output-formatting

The best way I can come up with to say "show me this fraction as a decimal number to M places, don't use scientific notation" is:

```
NumberForm[N[1/998001,2994],ExponentFunction->(Null&)]
```

It seems like that's an awful lot of typing for a very simple request.

Is it possible to say it more concisely?

Comment: I think that is the canonical way, but that doesn't mean there isn't something more terse.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it altogether. But if you find yourself doing it a lot, you can always use SetOptions...

Comment: I can't use any of these values to plot becasue their Head changes to NumberForm and graphs don't understand this form. I need to plot and have the tooltip show decimal form, any suggested alterations to the above to make it work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can express any fraction/number to arbitrary decimal places by using a backtick followed by number of digits required. For example:

```
In[1]:= 4/3`20
Out[1]= 1.3333333333333333333
```

This is the same as `N[4/3, 20]`. Now combine this with `AccountingForm`, which never uses scientific notation to get the output that you desire.

```
AccountingForm[1/998001`2994]
Out[2]//AccountingForm= 0.0000010020030040050060070080090100110120130140...
```

However, be aware that `AccountingForm` uses parentheses for negative numbers:

```
AccountingForm[-1/998001`2994]
Out[3]//AccountingForm= (0.00000100200300400500600700800901001101201301401501601....
```

---

Daniel Lichtblau has a good point that although using `` ` ``instead of `N` might be shorter in this case, in general, it might not give the same result — for example, compare the digits of `` Log[2`50] `` and `N[Log[2],50]`. You'll see that they differ in the last couple of digits. However, for small use cases, the difference might be insignificant.

Comment: I also thought of AccountingForm (and RealDigits), but I think the negative numbers are an issue.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, but I also noticed that it uses `()` for negative numbers, which could be used to distinguish if one were to use this only for quick visual checking

Comment: I am voting for this since I think AccountingForm comes closest.

Comment: Might just use N[...,m]. Check difference between Log[2`20] and N[Log[2],20]. The former will lose a digit. (Might not be important for the purposes at hand, though.)

Comment: Can avoid `()` for negative numbers with `AccountingForm[-1/998001\`2994, NumberSigns -> {"-", ""}]`, although that may exceed the "awful lot of typing" limit...

Comment: Of course those Log calculations give different answers. The former is Log[(2 with 50 digit precision)], the latter is (Log[2] with 50 digit precision). Taking ``Log[2`50]`` and ``Log[N[2,50]]`` gives exactly the same answer.

Answer (score 23):

You could always set `$Post` to have this happen automatically.

```
format[x_Real] := NumberForm[x, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)];
format[x_] := x;
$Post = format;
```

Now,

```
N[1/998001, 50]
```

returns

```
0.0000010020030040050060070080090100110120130140150160170
```

Even better, `$Post` is applied at display time, thus

```
Head[%]
```

returns `Real`.

Answer (score 2):

This post got many upvotes now. But no one mentioned [`DecimalForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DecimalForm.html) which is introduced in ver 11.2, 2017

```
DecimalForm[N[1/998001, 2994]]
```

gives exactly what you need.