# Representation of negative exponents

Tags: output-formatting, number-representation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to improve “show me this decimal number to M places, don't use scientific notation”?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/771/way-to-improve-show-me-this-decimal-number-to-m-places-dont-use-scientific-no)

How can I expand e.g. number 1.*10^-8 so that there would be no exponents? It should look like 0.00000001.

Answer (score 3):

Representation of numbers of handled with [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html). Choice of exponent to display is determined by its [`ExponentFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExponentFunction.html) option. If you never want an exponent displayed, this option should be a function that always returns Null, i.e. `(Null &)`:

```
NumberForm[1.*10^-8, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]
(* 0.00000001 *)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking that NumberForm might be the answer but I did not know how exactly do it.

Comment: What if you *always* want to show the exponent? I am having problems transforming some numbers so that they show the exponents instead of the full number as in your output :\ applying only `NumberForm[300000000,2]` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [`NumberForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumberForm.html), [`AccountingForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AccountingForm.html) may be a useful shorthand:

```
AccountingForm[1.*10^-8]
```

> 0.00000001

Negative numbers are displayed (by default) in parentheses:

```
AccountingForm[-1.*10^-8]
```

> (0.00000001)