# compile function and floating points

Tags: compile

The compile function I have written computes a table of relative frequencies of some data. Thus, the output is a list of increase elements, p, in [0,1]. Since I have say 1000 data points the elements p are equal to x/1000 and x in [0,1000]. Hence, each p should  have a maximum of three positions after the decimal point. However, if I run the compile function then values having many more positions after the decimal point appear. However, this appears to be true not for all elements of the resulting list.

For example, let the true p equal 0.894, then the compile output reads p = 0.8949999999999.

How can I force the result to be 0.894?

Unfortunately, `Round[p,1./1000.]`does not work within the compile function. It does not work either if I apply `Round`to the resulting `list`. What works, but seem inefficient, is `Round[list,1/1000]//N`. Thanks for help.

Comment: Executing `RealDigits[894/1000, 2]` will help you see what's going on: 0.894 has a nontrivial infinitely repeating expansion in base 2 (exactly like, say, 1/3 or 1/7 have repeating expansions base 10), proving that it's impossible to represent 0.894 exactly in base 2 floating point representations.

Answer (score 4):

This is a question about [floating-point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error), not Mathematica as such.

The Mathematica part of the answer is that using `Compile` means that all computations happen with machine numbers, and then it's a question of understanding what floating-point arithmetic does. See also [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

A simple demonstration of the dangers of using floating-point numbers as if they had infinite accuracy:

```
y = 0.01 $MachineEpsilon
x = 1. + y;
x - 1
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't like this example. It should give `False` under any meaningful definition of epsilon, but doesn't because of the extra tolerance of ``Log[2, 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance]`` bits applied by `Equal`. If you want a number for which `1 + x == x` gives `True` and don't wish to unduly abuse IEEE754, I would suggest using ``x = (1 + 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance)/2 $MachineEpsilon`` instead. Alternatively, you could use ``Internal`CompareNumeric[0, 1 + $MachineEpsilon/2, 1]``.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I don't understand what you're saying I'm afraid. Can you unpack this a bit? (also, any thoughts on [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13004/16)?)

Comment: `$MachineEpsilon` is *defined as* the smallest number for which `x + x $MachineEpsilon == x` gives `False` in an ordinary floating-point comparison. In *Mathematica*, there is an extra tolerance--``Log[2, 10^Internal`$EqualTolerance]`` bits are effectively chopped off each comparand before the comparison is done, so by writing `1 + $MachineEpsilon == 1` you are basically requesting the result of `1. == 1`, which entirely defeats the point. Because of the tolerance, you need to use a larger number than `$MachineEpsilon` for the example to be meaningful.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I see your point (I was just experimentally looking for a small enough number so to my shame did not even know what `MachineEpsilon` is supposed to be). How do you feel about `x = 1. + 0.001 $MachineEpsilon;x - 1` as an example, then?

Comment: That'd be better, but 0.001 is too small. Use 0.5 instead. :) Sorry, no thoughts on the tridiagonal matrix construction--just stopped by for 10 minutes as a break from thesis-writing. I'll have a proper look after I'm done, 2 weeks from now.

Comment: @OleksandrR. OK good thanks. Good luck with the writing :)

Comment: Thanks guys. Although I was hoping for a more practical suggestion the answer and comments are truly enlightening. I will stick to my original solution.

Comment: @chris if it's about displaying them in a compact way, take a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/771/16) question (and answers to it)