# How can I solve precision problem

Tags: output-formatting

I want to set 2 decimal places, whether it's real Number or anything.for that purpose I wrote the following function.

```
 decimalPlaces[number_]:=SetPrecision[number, 3]
```

case 1:

If you pass `3`as a argument,it should returns `3.00`.

case 2:

if you pass `3.98967465684` as a argument,it should returns `3.98`.

case 3:

if you pass `394` as a argument,it should returns `394.00`.But it returns `394`.

case 4:

if you pass `394.985674` as a argument,it should returns `394.98`.But it returns `394`.

finally,my function was not satisfying the case 3,4 testcases

How can I solve this.

Fell free,If you want to edit my question.

Thank you.

Comment: @Artes you used `NumberForm` but, NumberForm acts as a "wrapper", which affects printing, but not evaluation.
But in my program, after completion of the above calculation,I am doing some computation by using the above value.

Comment: Your question title is misleading. It is neither a precision problem nor a problem with Mathematica. Do you want a special kind of rounding or display?

Comment: @YvesKlett it's precision problem.I will edit my question.

Comment: @subbu The linked post comletely answers your question. If you are confused you should  think about e.g. this `Table[N[3.999999976565463548438, k], {k, 10}]`. It says enough to understand your problem.

Comment: @artes if you look at example 2 you see the question is not purely about the number of digits. There's also some kind of rounding down involved.

Comment: @all I edited my question.can you check it once

Comment: You say it returns 394. But that's not actually true. The more precise statement to make is that what it returns *is displayed as 394*. Which is not the same. Question about displaying numbers have been posted before. See e.g. [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/771/way-to-improve-show-me-this-decimal-number-to-m-places-dont-use-scientific-no). Therefore I vote to close.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Perhaps I don't understand what the OP really wants, but I think e.g. this works like he wanted e.g. `NumberForm[394, {3, 2}]` as well as `NumberForm[Floor[394, 0.01], {3, 2}]` while `Floor[394, 0.01]` alone does not.

Comment: @artes but he also wants 3.989 to map to 3.98, not 3.99.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The OP changed example, before there had been  `3.999999976565463548438`

Comment: @artes yeah, nasty habit.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries `NumberForm` also not useful,because `NumberForm` is a wrapper,it doesn't allow to any evaluation.so `NumberForm` is not work.

Comment: You could try to adapt the answer of mark McClure in the link I provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
decimalPlaces[number_] := SetAccuracy[Floor[number, 0.01], 3]
```

do what you want?

Comment: sorry,your code not satisfying the `example 1`and `example 4`.

Comment: @subbu you weren't very clear about whether you wanted the output to look like that or whether its *value* should be like that. In the former case just use `NumberForm` in addition to `Floor`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries If I use `NumberForm` with `Floor`, I end up with not number.

Comment: @niren.That's why I differentiated between the value of the result and its displayed form. The number Mathematica displays is not actually exactly what it has in memory, but only to, I believe, 6 decimal places. So, Floor alone is sufficient to restrict the number of places to two. If you want it to display that way you have to change formatting rules, for instance, with NunberForm ( but there are more possibilities).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I edited my question.can you check once

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I don't care about the value of the result. I do care about only displayed form.

Comment: @niren that's why I advised to use NunberForm (you used it with additional arguments, didn't you?), but then you say it's not a number. You're contradicting yourself.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries even though I care about only displayed form, these result will go for further computation, there I could do nothing with no number.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries FTFY. It passes all the test cases, although this casual approach to precision and rounding will inevitably result in wrong answers somewhere down the line. OP's problem, not ours; hope he won't come crying to us...