# Problem with working precision

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I have tried to resolve the problem of the following link [How can I solve precision problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23931/how-can-i-solve-precision-problem)

I can tell the problem described in that link shortly here, It's no mater how many precision is there after decimal(.) the result should be 2 or 3 precision after decimal as per user requirement.e.g

```
N[10/3]
3
```

Output should be as per user wish precision as 2.

```
3.33
3.00
```

There I found `NumberForm[]` function as a solution, since the `NumberForm[]` function is wrap up the result, I can't get the result as number out of it.

I tried like this

```
NumberForm[N[10/3],{4,2}]
NumberForm[3, {4, 2}]
```

Output am getting is

```
3.33
3.00
```

But when I try to do further operation, it's not computing

```
NumberForm[N[10/3], {4, 2}] + 1
NumberForm[3, {4, 2}] + 1
```

Output

```
1+3.33
1+3.00
```

I tried other way also which follows

```
ToExpression[ToString[NumberForm[3, {4, 2}]]]
```

OutPut

```
3.
```

but I need output as 3.00. Help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Is [`SetAccuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetAccuracy.html) what you want?

```
a = N[10/3, {∞, 3}]
```

> 3.33

```
b = 3``3
```

> 3.00

```
a + 1
```

> 4.33

```
b + 1
```

> 4.00

```
394.985674``3
```

> 394.99

Please note `Accuracy` is a different concept from `Precision`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$PrePrint` global parameter:

```
$PrePrint = If[MatchQ[#, _?NumericQ], NumberForm[#, {4, 2}], #] &;
```

Note: if you dont want the way rationals will be represented after setting the global variable (e.g. $3.00/4.00$) then use this instead

```
$PrePrint = If[MatchQ[#, Except[_Rational,_?NumericQ]], NumberForm[#, {4, 2}], #] &;
```

---

Update:

if you just want it for the `InputField` command try this instead

```
InputField[Dynamic[ToString@NumberForm[b, {4, 2}]], String]
```

Comment: I have problem with your answer, I need to give the result to `InputField` the output I got is not I expected.b=3 `InputField[Dynamic[b], Number]`. I got result 3 alone in `InputField` not 3.00

Comment: @niren Indeed but you didn't ask that ...

Comment: @niren  This is closer to what you _really_ want: `InputField[Dynamic[ToString@NumberForm[b, {4, 2}]], String]`

Comment: I want only `Number` in `InputField`, Since the result from the `InputField` will go for further calculation.

Comment: @niren but inside the input field you cant do any calculations just input a number. You have to explain _exactly_ what you want.

Comment: yes you are right, I can't do any calculation inside the input field but I can do calculation out of input field on the value after displayed in input field.

Comment: @niren outside the input field the setting `$PrePrint` works just fine, if you want in the output the specific format of course ...