# How to use million separator on my output?

Tags: output-formatting

On the question [Way to improve "show me this decimal number to M places, don't use scientific notation"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/771/way-to-improve-show-me-this-decimal-number-to-m-places-dont-use-scientific-no) I learned how to automatically not use scientific notation with:

```
format[x_Real] := NumberForm[x, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)];
format[x_] := x;
$Post = format;
```

Then my numbers are outputting better than before as :

```
4096^2*12*3.6`20
724775731.20000000000
```

But it is missing the miliar separator as comma `,`. For example, the number `724775731.20000000000` should output as `724,775,731.20000000000` so I can understand it easily.

Can the output the show as `724,775,731.20000000000` instead of `724775731.20000000000`?

---

Related:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark

Comment: Look up the `DigitBlock` and `NumberSeparator` options. Do read the whole doc page for `NumberForm[]` while you're at it.

Comment: Take a look at Preferences -> Appearance -> Numbers -> Formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments, I find out how to set it automatically to `` ` `` option:

```
format[x_Real]:=NumberForm[x,ExponentFunction->(Null&),DigitBlock->3,NumberSeparator->","];
format[x_]:=x;
$Post=format;
```

Now these:

```
4096^2*12*3.6`10
4096^3`20
```

Outputs as:

```
724,775,731.2
68,719,476,736.000,000,0
```