# Accuracy and precision control for a simple calculation

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, units

Consider a very simple calculation: $231 \times (2.54) ^ 3$, which is the number of cubic cm in a US gallon.

On my phone app calculator I got the exact answer, which is $3785.411784$.

On *Mathematica*, doing the same calculation `231 * (2.54)^3` I got `3785.41`.

Even with `N[231 * 2.54^3, 100]` etc. I got the same (imprecise) answer.

By converting the whole calculation to involve integers `(254^3 * 231 /1000000)` the answer was exact.

The `Precision` function kept indicating `MachinePrecision`, even when using `N[]` with a large number of significant figures.

**How can I increase the precision beyond `MachinePrecision` for trivial calculations like this?**

What if I have more complicated calculations involving exponents or other?

I would want to avoid accumulating loss of precision in each calculation.

Comment: `N[]` won't convert machine precision to arbitrary precision.  You could try showing the full result: `Style[231*2.54^3, PrintPrecision -> 17]` or `FullForm[231*2.54^3]`.  Or you could feed arbitrary-precision numbers as input: ``231*2.54`100^3`` (tho 100 digits is overkill).

Comment: Read the Tech Note ["Numbers"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  In the event that there was a lengthy calculation with many similar constructs in it similar to 2.54^3, would Mathematica treat each intermediate with a full 15 or so digits of precision, or would each intermediate or sub-section of the calculations have only 7 or so digits, with accumulating error?    If so, if extreme precision was needed, it may be necessary to go through each section of the calculation to expand precision?

Comment: I am seeing from this discussion that a good practice would be to define and store constants with the desired level of precision, prior to a calculation; this would probably improve readability of the code as well.  So for example to begin with cminch=2.54`20.  Then cminch^3 instead of 2.54^3.

Comment: Numbers entered with a decimal point and no backtick specifying a precision are treated as machine precision (typically 64-bit floats, aka [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) or double-precision).  They have a 53-bit mantissa, which gives you about 15.95 digits of precision. (Despite having less than 16 digits of precision, it takes 17 in some edge cases to distinguish distinct binary floating-point numbers; e.g. `Style[0.4 {1 - $MachineEpsilon/2, 1}, PrintPrecision -> 16]` and retry with `17`.) The default value for `PrintPrecision` is `6`.

Comment: The conversion from inches to centimeters is exact: 1 in is exactly (by definition) 2.54 cm. In Mathematica we can express this exactness with a rational number, carrying infinite accuracy, and getting converted to the right amount of significance depending on circumstance: `cminch = 254/100`. Then follow what @user56489 says.

Answer (score 6):

First off, the default display for finite precision numbers includes just a few digits. But the 15 or so digits of precision are all there:

```
FullForm[231*2.54^3]
```

`3785.411784'`

Secondly, when you tried this:

```
N[231*2.54^3, 100]
```

The 2.54 had the standard precision, and you can't perform calculations at a higher precision that the elements within it. But there is a way to set precision for a number higher.

```
2.54`100
```

tells Mathematica to use 100 digits of precision. So, you could do this if you really wanted to:

```
231*2.54`100^3
```

`3785.41178400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 5):

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Gallons"], "Cubic Centimeters"] // N[#, 10] &
```

> Quantity[3785.411784, ("Centimeters")^3]

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Gallons"], "Liters"] // N[#, 10] &
```

> Quantity[3.785411784, "Liters"]

Answer (score 3):

After Mark McClure's post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/774/363) — handy up to 16 digits

```
form[x_Real] := DecimalForm[x, Length@First@RealDigits@x];
form[x_] := x;
$Post = form;

v = 231*2.54^3
```

> 3785.411784

```
Head[v]
```

> Real

Unset with `$Post=.`

Without further measures, limited to default precision

```
v = -12345678901234.567
```

> -12345678901234.57